# Using BlockUI for Dialogs in PrimeVue

Tags: primevue

I'm using PrimeVue and I want to show a dialog. Everything works fine, but when opening the dialog, I've 2 ajax calls that must be done to fill the dropdown boxes inside my dialog. So I want block the dialog until the ajax requests came back using BlockUI but unfortunately it doesn't work. I finally reduced my source to the following few lines:

```js
<template lang="pug">
BlockUI(:blocked="true")
  Dialog(visible modal header="test")
</template>
```

My expectation is that the Dialog is blocked - similar to what happens when I click on "Block" on https://primevue.org/blockui/#basic

But currently it looks like this:

[image]

The BlockUI component doesn't block the dialog. I already searched a bit and on some pages I read that dialogs aren't compatible yet, but the entries are from 2013 on current PrimeVue documentation I cannot find such a hint anymore. So is it still not supported to block dialogs and am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide an example code of how to make API calls precisely? In which component does this happen? Do you execute it during the Dialog mount event?